counting function into integration
Could someone please tell me how one write some counting function over the zeros of L function in terms of the Riemann Stieltjes integration wrt the the same counting function? I know Riemann Stieltjes integration but unable to understand the inbetween steps and wish to know some more examples in this regard. Any help or hint would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Are you asking how to evaluate the Riemann Stieltjes integral $$\int\limits_a^b\psi_o(x),d\psi_o(x)=\int\limits_a^b\psi_o(x),\psi_o'(x),dx\tag{1}$$ of the explicit formula $$\psi_o(x)=x-\lim\limits_{T\to\infty} \left(\sum\limits_{|\Im(\rho)|<T}\frac{x^\rho}{\rho}\right)-\log(2,\pi)+\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^{-2,n}}{2,n}\=x-\lim\limits_{T\to\infty} \left(\sum\limits_{|\Im(\rho)|<T}\frac{x^\rho}{\rho}\right)-\log(2,\pi)-\frac{1}{2},\log\left(1-\frac{1}{x^2}\right),\qquad x>1\tag{2}$$ for the second Chebyshev function $$\psi(x)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^x \Lambda(n)\tag{3}$$ for example?
